# ffmpeg erorr as "video4linux2 Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains corrupted data (0 bytes). " when captured image,in beaglebone black,

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, beagleboneblack, v4l2

when i'm capturing a image using ffmpeg 4.2.1 in debian 9.5 of Beaglebone black its not showing this error 
as
     [video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x2e0f1e0] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains corrupted data (0 bytes).
 i used this command to capture image
"ffmpeg -y -i /dev/video0 -ss 00:00:06 -vframes 1 image.jpg"